# SVN Repository Folder overwritten but has some old svn folders in it, some missing

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, corrupt

Right. I'm in a bit of a mess.

Due to a complicated set of events I had to bypass SVN and update a live website with a new version by copying it in in-situ after deleting the old one.

We normally keep the website in sync by updating it via SVN after devs commit changes via their local working copies. I now need to commit the new website code to SVN so the devs can update their working copies with this new version.

Problem is that some svn folders seem to have been left behind, and in other folders there are no svn files at all.

SVN point blank refuses to commit the new code as it says error, directory (foo) containing working copy admin area is missing.

Is there any way to basically say to SVN, look, ignore the SVN status of this folder and subfolders, but just overwrite the version you have with this code? Or something?

I'm using tortoise SVN on my local machine/working copy (which is currently the old version before the changes), and on the live server we have a command line SVN.

I have a copy of the old website before it was overwritten, maybe if I copy all the svn files back into the structure from there, will that work?

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are missing `.svn` folders within the folder structure, SVN is just going to refuse to commit the changes as it doesn't have the complete information it expects.

In this case I would:

1. Move the fixed code into a temporary location
2. Remove all `.svn` folders from this code

   - `find /path/to/moved/code -type d -name .svn | xargs rm -rf`
3. Re-checkout the latest code from SVN
4. Copy the fixed code back into the SVN repository location

Comment: Ah, that's a possibility! I'll have a go and let you know how it goes @jas_raj